# C# Linq unique not work on lists

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying with the following code to check if a list contains duplicated data:

```
    internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Obj>() { new Obj() { id = "1", name = "1" }, new Obj() { id = "1", name = "1" } };
        Console.WriteLine(AllItemsAreUnique(list));
    }

    public static bool AllItemsAreUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items.Distinct().Count() == items.Count();
    }
}

internal class Obj
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

And the result is true! Why?

Comment: Because "two objects having the same properties" does not mean "two equal objects", see duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

By default, the comparison will use references and in this case, the two object references are not the same.

You need to implement `IEquatable<T>` to provide a type-specific `Equals()` method for `Distinct()` to use.

Comment: Mmm... there is no easiersolution? Thanks.

Comment: Fairly Easy:

    internal class Obj : IEquitable<Obj>
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;

        public bool Equals(Obj other)
        {
            reutrn id == other.id && name == other.name;
        }
    }

I omitted some code that is necessary: overriding Equals(object) and GetHashCode(). However, it won't be a big matter even if you don't override them.